# SQL SERVER: Many to many relationships across multiple tables with hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two types of tables.  Composition Tables, and Test Tables.
Composition Tables are a many to many hierarchy for each other.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
[AID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[AOnlyThing] [nchar](10) NULL,
[AOtherThing] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [BID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [BOnlyThing] [nchar](10) NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[C](
[CID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CProperty] [nchar](10) NUL
)
```

A is made of B which is made of C, where an item from C can be used in multiple items from B  (same for A).  So I have many to many relationship tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AB](
    [ABID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    AID [bigint] NOT NULL,
    BID [bigint] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BC](
    [BCID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    BID [bigint] NOT NULL,
    CID [bigint] NOT NULL
)
```

Then I have Test Tables: X, Y ... about 100 of them

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[X](
    [XID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [XTest1] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [XTest2] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [XTest3] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Y](
    Measurement bigint NOT NULL, 
    Test2 float NOT NULL
)
```

I'm trying to find a good way to join these tables so that I can run any test on table A, B, or C.

I've tried putting specific Test ID columns in the composition tables or specific compositions in the test tables.  This seemed way too messy.

I've tried Creating a test table with object_ids and IDs for the composition tables and test tables.

```
Create Table TestTable(
    TestTableID bigint NOT NULL, 
    CompObjectID bigint NOT NULL, 
    CompID bigint NOT NULL, 
    TestObjectID bigint NOT NULL, 
    TestID bigint NOT NULL
)
```

This at least let me get a list of all Tests that were Run on it.

```
SELECT A.*, [TestTable].*, sys.tables.name
FROM A INNER JOIN [Test Table] ON object_ID('A') = 
[TestTable].CompObjectID AND A.AID = TestTable.CompID
INNER JOIN sys.tables on sys.tables.object_id = TestObjectID
WHERE A.AID = 1
```

The end goal is to be able to query A and find it's full component stack and with all tests that were run on each piece.

Comment: Why can't you just join B & C to the query you have that gets all the tests?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. From a, join a to b, join b to c, join c to test ?

Comment: @PommeDeTerre, I want to be able to join any A, B, or C to XTest and/or YTest

Comment: How can you use the xtest1, xtest2... To the value in A (there are two) and use the same thing on B (only one value) ? Could you provide an example with values and expected result please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "...I can run any test on table A, B, or C...". The join seems pretty simple. Can you add some sample data? The solution seems quite simple to be honest.